# Cannot set property -hashed_password of null , of addFollower method in nodejs app

Tags: node.js

My controller/user.js file has the following

```
exports.addFollower= (req,res )=>{
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.followId, {
        $push:{followers: req.body.user_Id}
    },
             {new : true}
    )
    .populate('following', '_id name')
    .populate('followers', '_id name')
    .exec((err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:"This is an error "
            })
        }
        result.hashed_password= undefined;
        result.salt = undefined;
        res.json(result)
 
    })
}
```

And my routes/user.js file has the following

const express = require('express');

```
const {userById ,allUsers, getUser,updateUser,deleteUser ,userPhoto
, addFollowing,
addFollower, removeFollowing, removeFollower
}= require('../controllers/user');
const {requireSignin} = require('../controllers/auth');

const router = express.Router();

router.put('/user/follow', requireSignin, addFollowing,addFollower );
router.put('/user/unfollow', requireSignin, removeFollowing, removeFollower);
```

User Model is as follows

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let uuidv1 = require('uuidv1');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true

    },
    hashed_password:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    created:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    updated:Date,
    photo:{
        data:Buffer,
        contentType:String
    },
    about:{
        type:String,
        trim:true
    },
    following:[{type:ObjectId , ref:"User"}],
    followers:[{type:ObjectId, ref:"User"}]

});



//virtual field
userSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password){
    //create a temporary variable called _password
    this._password =password
    //generate a timestamp 
    this.salt = uuidv1();   
    //encrypt password
    this.hashed_password= this.encryptPassword(password);   
})
.get(function(){
    return this._password
})

//methods
userSchema.methods = {

   authenticate:function(plainText){

     return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password

   },

    encryptPassword:function (password){
        if(!password)   
        return "user SCHEMA error";
        
        try{
            return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt)
            .update(password)
            .digest('hex');
             
        }
        catch(err) {

            return "userSchema error 2  ";


        }
    }
}


module.exports= mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
```

But when I hit the following Route /user/follow with valid token i get the following error

TypeError: Cannot set property 'hashed_password' of null
at rfs\nodeapi\controllers\user.js:180:31

line 180 refers to this section

```
exports.addFollower= (req,res )=>{
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.followId, {
        $push:{followers: req.body.user_Id}
    },
             {new : true}
    )
    .populate('following', '_id name')
    .populate('followers', '_id name')
    .exec((err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:"This is an error "
            })
        }
        result.hashed_password= undefined;
        result.salt = undefined;
        res.json(result)


    })

}
```

How do I debug this?

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is, when you see this error please cross check what your fetch request is like, even with a small case difference mongoose will error out , in my case the following happened..

Upon Checking the fetch request , found that the follow_Id was written as follow_id , in the addFollower method

```
export const follow = (user_Id, token,follow_Id)=>{



    return   fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/user/follow `,{
          method:"PUT",
          headers:{
              Accept:"application/json",
              "Content-Type":"application/json",
              Authorization:`Bearer ${token}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({user_Id,follow_Id})

        
      })
      .then(response =>{
          return response.json();
      })
      .catch(err=>console.log(err)
   
      )
    
  }
```

Correct add Follower method

```
exports.addFollower = (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.follow_Id, { $push: { followers: req.body.user_Id } }, { new: true })
        .populate('following', '_id name')
        .populate('followers', '_id name')
        .exec((err, result) => {
            console.log("result " , result);
            console.log(" req.params.follow_id " , req.params.follow_Id);
            console.log(" req.body.user_Id " , req.body.user_Id);
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: err
                });
            }
            result.hashed_password = undefined;
            result.salt = undefined;
            res.json(result);
        });
};
```